# Texture painting pixels fading

Tags: texture-painting

I’m currently texture painting on my model. I have faced an issue where the pixels are fading out at the edge. I would like to remove this or at least prevent it from happening in the future. An example is below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand, could you please show a screenshot and also the UV Editor and the Shader Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your brush falloff uses the constant preset:

[image]

And disable Anti Aliasing:

[image]

Result:

[image]